# Calling parameterised viewmodel constructor when using WPF Prism / Mahapps HamburgerMenu control

Tags: wpf, mvvm, constructor, prism, mahapps.metro

Apologies for the long post as trying to get as much info out. I am using WPF (.NET Framework 4.8), Prism 7, Prism.Unity and MahApps.  Almost all of my view models require parameterised constructors (injected with dependencies). I was making use of the built in Prism ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel to wire up the view models (i.e. prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True").  All was working fine but this meant there were two instances of the viewmodel created, once by using AutoWireViewModel and again by calling the parameterised constructor behind the scenes (see Brian Lagunas' comment [Avoid Prism AutoWireViewModel Creating the ViewModel Twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42539875/avoid-prism-autowireviewmodel-creating-the-viewmodel-twice)).
Therefore I have set the AutoWireViewModel value to False and am now creating the viewmodel in the code behind of each view. I am able to inject into the view constructors the dependencies required when creating the viewmodel - this is also working fine.
The problem I am having is when I am trying to use the Mahapps HamburgerMenu control. This contains menu items for each sub view.  From what I can determine is each sub view needs a parameterless constructor, but I require a parameterised view constructor (injected with dependencies needed to create/call the viewmodel constructor). The exceptions/innerexceptions I receive are:

"No matching constructor found on type 'MyCompany.Wpf.Modules.Admin.Views.AdminDataGrid'. You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct this type.' Line number '236' and line position '34'."
"No default constructor found for type 'MyCompany.Wpf.Modules.Admin.Views.AdminDataGrid'. You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct this type."

If I add a paraterless constructor in the AdminDataGrid view then I get no error but I am unable to create the view model and pass in the dependency.

My code is as follows:

AdminMainView code containing HamburgerMenu (the problem sub view is named AdminDataGrid):

```
<Controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="HamburgerMenuControl"
                                HamburgerWidth="48"
                                IsPaneOpen="True"
                                CanResizeOpenPane="True"
                                ItemInvoked="HamburgerMenuControl_OnItemInvoked"
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"
                                OptionsItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"
                                SelectedIndex="0"
                                Style="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.HamburgerMenu.Ripple}"
                                VerticalScrollBarOnLeftSide="False">
    <!--  Items  -->
    <Controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
        <Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
            <Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem Icon="{iconPacks:FontAwesome Kind=TableSolid}" Label="Data Grid">
                <Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                    <views:AdminDataGrid />
                </Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
            </Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem>
        </Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
    </Controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
```

Code behind for AdminDataGrid view. The second constructor is what I would like to call:
    public partial class AdminDataGrid : UserControl, IAdminDataGrid
    {
        // I have had to add this to get the code to build/run.
        public AdminDataGrid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    // This is the constructor I would like to call
    public AdminDataGrid(ICustomerService service)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new AdminDataGridViewModel(service);
    }
}
```

AdminDataGridViewModel :

```
public class AdminDataGridViewModel : BindableBase, IAdminDataGridViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customers;
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
    {
        get => this._customers;
        set => SetProperty(ref _customers, value);
    }

    public AdminDataGridViewModel(ICustomerService service)
    {
        Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
        Customers.AddRange(service.GetAllCustomers().OrderBy(c => c.LastName));
    }
}
```

I have tried created interfaces for the AdminDataGrid/AdminDataGridViewModel and the classes inherit from them, the module manager code is:

```
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.Register<IAdminDataGrid, AdminDataGrid>();
    containerRegistry.Register<IAdminDataGridViewModel, AdminDataGridViewModel>();
}
```

The AdminMainView code behind. NOTE: I inject the IAdminDataGridViewModel object and expose this as a property on the AdminMainViewModel (idea being to set the DataContext to this property for the views:AdminDataGrid menu item - but not sure how to or if this would work).

```
public AdminMainView(IAdminDataGridViewModel adminDataGridViewModel)
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new AdminMainViewModel(adminDataGridViewModel);
}
```

AdminMainViewModel constructor:

```
public AdminMainViewModel(IAdminDataGridViewModel adminDataGridViewModel)
{
    this.AdminDataGridViewModel = adminDataGridViewModel;
}
```

How may I get the HamburgerMenu control to use the parameterised constructor when is renders the views:AdminDataGrid item?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This markup tries to create an instance of the `AdminDataGrid` using the default constructor:

```
<views:AdminDataGrid />
```

This obviously doesn't work when the view doesn't have such as a constuctor defined. It means that you cannot set the `Tag` property of the `HamburgerMenuIconItem` like this in XAML.

If you however set it programmatically in the code-behind, you could either get a reference to your registry and resolve the view model from there or construct the view model yourself:

```
adminItem.Tag = new AdminMainView(new AdminMainViewModel());
```

**XAML:**

```
<Controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
    <Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
        <Controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem x:Name="adminItem" Icon="{iconPacks:FontAwesome Kind=TableSolid}" Label="Data Grid" />
    </Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
</Controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
```

Either way, the XAML processor won't resolve the dependencies for you.

Comment: @Thanks mm8 for the response and information.  I have updated my XAML HamburgerMenuIconItem elements as suggested and am now creating the elements (view and viewmodel) in code behind.  Works perfectly.

Comment: For reference, I no longer add the IAdminDataGrid to the container, but still add/use IAdminDataGridViewModel by injecting this into AdminMainView's constructor.  I do this so that I do noy need to inject each dependency needed for creating the sub view/viewmodel.  The original qu is a cut down version of the dependencies/number of menu items I actually use in my project.

Answer (score 1):

> How may I get the HamburgerMenu control to use the parameterised constructor when is renders the views:AdminDataGrid item?

You won't. Controls are supposed to have parameterless constructors, that's what the `ViewModelLocator` was invented for to circumvent.

I'd just use that to have the view models created (*with* all the required dependencies as constructor parameters) and not create and assign the data context manually.

That being said, there's also the option to go view model-first, and most of the time it's preferable to view-first.

Comment: Thanks for the response and information - I will bear this in mind. I would like to use the viewmodel first approach but sadly do not have the time to refactor the work I have done so far. This is my first project using WPF/MVVM/Prism and now that I have some knowledge my next project will use viewmodel first approach.

Comment: Well, you could just remove the view model creation from the view constructor and instead set `AutowireViewModel` and end up with a view model created with all its dependencies in your view's datacontext. That's not that large of a refactoring.

Comment: I originally had AutowireViewModel set to True.  However as I mentioned in the original post this was causing the ViewModels to be created twice for some reason (see the link in original post). It seems I have misunderstood the link - as I do not explicitly create views/viewmodels anywhere in my code (all done via XAML).  I have posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360352/prism-wpf-views-viewmodels-being-created-twice
Thanks.

Comment: They key point of `AutowireViewModel` is that you do _not_ create the view models yourself, not in code-behind nor in xaml - instead they just magically appear.